# Do Americans use the term "garburator" or is there a better equivalent?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, word-usage, american-english, blending

Is it obsolete to use the term *garburator* to refer to a garbage disposal unit in a kitchen? If it is, do we have a better term to replace it with?

Also, what is the etymology of this word?

Comment: I never heard the word, but I love it!

Comment: Yeaaaaaaah , me too , it's lovely

Comment: There's a brand of garbage disposals named *In-sink-erator*, which is another terrible pun.

Comment: Well-known word in Canada since at least 1965, when my grandfather installed one. I don't know if it referred to a specific brand at that time.

Comment: Interesting word. I cannot recall having consciously heard it before, but I instantly and instinctively knew what it was when I read the title of this thread. As for the etymology, it is obviously a mix of ‘carburator’ (also spelled ‘carburetor/carburettor/carburetter’), as in the thing you have in your car engine, and ‘garbage’.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As an American, I've never heard this word before today. I refer to it simply as a *garbage disposal*, without the word *unit*.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/garburator claims that this word is specific to Canada, so I assume it might have been a Canadian brand.

Comment: You are correct , but i've heard it lots of times in Tv .but thanks anyway

Comment: @BenyaminHamidekhoo, what country have you heard it in?  I too have never heard it and this is the first time I've ever seen it.

Comment: I heard it on a TV Series called " How i met your mother " , America . There was a gal named Robin . She used this word one or twice i guess.

Comment: That could make it a "proprietary eponym" where a trademark is used for the general type of product.

Comment: @BenyaminHamidekhoo the character Robin in that show is Canadian, and some of the humour in it comes from views Americans and Canadians have of each other, so it might well have been used precisely because Americans wouldn't use it. Incidentally, some other humour in that show comes from the group having pet coinages that nobody uses, so there'd be more than a few cases where they'd say something that isn't really found anywhere at all.

Comment: This term is used in Vermont, not just Canada. I'm a Vermonter.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry for *Garbage disposal unit* begins with the words "A *garbage disposal unit*, *waste disposal unit*, or *garburator* is a device..." but I could not find any evidence that any company named Garburator sold large numbers of such units or that any sold a product named Garburator in large numbers. The earliest company devoted to producing garbage disposal units (dating to 1940) was In-Sink-Erator, which was also the name of its product. I hadn't heard of it until we moved to a (U.S.) house that had one installed. I've never heard the term _garburator_ used in the wild.

Answer (score 5):

I heard the term years ago on the Red Green Show — again Canadian.  I was able to figure out what it was by the images of the unit and the discussion.  I had initially thought it was a brand but I have found nothing about such a brand anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

My whole family uses the word, but we're the only people I've heard use it in Florida. My mom's family is from Canada, so that might be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I use the word. I'm Canadian and living in the USA. I was surprised to find no results when searching the big box stores online for a new garburator. Hence, I ended up here. I assumed it was a universal name until now.

Comment: I've heard of it, but that's about as far as it goes.  Would not expect Home Despot sales droids to recognize the term.

Answer (score -2):

Garberator is a contraction of the words garbage & macerator